# Domain User Account Locks: Correct password used

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, group-policy, active-directory

I have a domain (DC is running Windows Server 2008 R2) and have the Account Lockout Policy enabled.  When a user attempts to log into their PC (with the correct password) they receive the following error:

> The referenced account is currently locked out and may not be logged on to.

I have unlocked the account within AD and disabled the account lockout policy (which has temporarily resolved this issue).

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Did this user have any failed attempts?  What was your policy set to (how many attempts before the account locks out)?

Comment: No. the user has not any attempts. he/she locked for no reason. and the policy for account security is the default policies.

Comment: How many domain controllers do you have? What is the client OS being used by the user?

Answer (score 2):

If the user has recently changed their password, this could be something trying to authenticate using the old password.

I'd suggest using [Account Lockout and Management Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=18465) ([click here for the instructions on using the Account Lockout and Management Tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738772%28WS.10%29.aspx)) by Microsoft to trace where the account is being locked out; this will help determine the cause.

Alternatively, if you update the post with the logs from your DC, I can attempt to trace it from there.

Comment: I think the bigger issue here is that the OP thinks they've disabled Account Lockout in their Domain Security Policy but, clearly, they haven't.

Comment: I think the OP disabled the Account Lockout GPO due to this issue (as a temporary fix) and this has resolved the issue...  But it's very vague.

Comment: That it is. I somehow think we'll never know...

Answer (score 1):

I know you've disabled the policy for mistypes but I'm curious, does the user have a mobile device connected their account? If that is the case, then the user needs to check that their passwords are updated correctly on their devices otherwise this can also cause a lockout on the machine.

Comment: No. The user just work on a single PC and don't have any Mobile Device.

Comment: do you also include RDP sessions on remote hosts? I've been caught out when an RDP login didn't exit properly, but was caching credentials.